# use select in rowsums

Tags: r, select, dplyr, rowsum

```
dataframe %>%
  select(thumb_p1_frac_1, thumb_p1_frac_2, thumb_p1_frac_3, thumb_p1_frac_4, thumb_p1_frac_5) %>%
  mutate(P1 = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE))
```

above works, but I want to remove the pipe of select and implement select select in mutate, like

```
dataframe %>%
  mutate(P1 = rowSums(., select(thumb_p1_frac_1, thumb_p1_frac_2, thumb_p1_frac_3, thumb_p1_frac_4, thumb_p1_frac_5), na.rm = TRUE))
```

it says:

no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Answer (score 0):

As your error said, you choose the wrong input to the `select()` function. The reason for this is that `select()` takes a `data.frame` but you only supply separate columns! So a solution to your problem is to give the `select()` command the `.` which represents the `data.frame` that you pipe through the `%>%`.

Hence, a correct code is

```
dataframe %>%
  mutate(P1 = rowSums(select(., thumb_p1_frac_1, thumb_p1_frac_2, 
                              thumb_p1_frac_3, thumb_p1_frac_4, thumb_p1_frac_5), 
                na.rm = TRUE))
```

Note that I pulled out the `.` from within `rowSums()` and instead used it in `select()`.